# Seeking parents' names for Shadrach/Shedrick Montgomery, born 1790 in Chester, Pennsylvania, USA?

Tags: 18th-century, birth-records, pennsylvania, will

My family is looking for our great-great grandfathers parents' names.

His name is Shadrach or Shedrick Montgomery, and he was born in Chester, Pennsylvania in 1790.

How can we find a birth record or parents wills without traveling to Pennsylvania?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take our 2-minute [Tour], if you have not already.  In a moment I'll use the **edit** button beneath your question to try and maximize its chances of attracting a potential answerer.  You are free to add or revise details in it at any time too.

Comment: If this is him in the [1860 US Federal Census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MC2P-9DK) then it is probably worth including the Family Search citation in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The US GenWeb project has a web page for the 1790 census for Chester County, PA.  Here's the link: http://www.usgwarchives.net/pa/chester/census.htm

If you click on the text file "indx04.txt" under the "1790 Census Index, Surnames," you'll see that there were six Montgomery heads of households in Chester County:

LAST_NAME         FIRST_NAME    PAGE   COL   LINE   FILE NAME    DIVISION

Montgomery        (Widow)       9      1     39     pg01c1.txt   East Nottingham

Montgomery        Ann           13     2     19     pg12c1.txt   New London

Montgomery        John          13     2     33     pg12c1.txt   New London

Montgomery        Michael       14     1     13     pg12c1.txt   New London

Montgomery        Robert        13     2     26     pg12c1.txt   New London

Montgomery        Samuel        13     2     27     pg12c1.txt   New London

Those were the Montgomerys who were living in Chester County, PA in 1790, the year your ancestor was born.  It's possible that one of them was his father or mother.

That website also has a list of wills from the county.  The only Montgomery will on that page is for Ann Montgomery: http://files.usgwarchives.net/pa/chester/wills/m/montgomery-a.txt  Unfortunately, her will does not mention a Shadrach or Shedrick, but you might be able to research the other listed relatives for clues to your ancestor.

```
                            ####
```

Another resource:

The official website for Chester County, PA (www.chesco.org) has a list of wills that they have on file, covering 1714 to 1923.  Here are the Montgomerys that they have from that time frame, along with the file date and township/location:

Montgomery Ann 1793 East Nottingham

Montgomery Hugh 1741

Montgomery James 1790 East Nottingham

Montgomery John 1730 New London

Montgomery John 1786 West Marlborough

Montgomery Joseph 1814 Upper Oxford

Montgomery Michael 1797

Montgomery Robert 1748 New London

Montgomery Robert 1790 New London

Montgomery Robert 1811 New London

Montgomery Susanna 1818 West Nantmeal

Montgomery William 1792 New London

You can e-mail them to request a photocopy of any of these wills.  It doesn't say on their website how much it costs, but usually it's a few bucks for photocopying, plus postage.  I hope this helps you find him!

Answer (score 1):

Among FamilySearch.org's "Pennsylvania Probate Records" microfilms for Chester County is the "Decedents record index 1716-1880".  The index includes the following:

1797  Michael Montgomery

1815  Robert Montgomery

1816  James Montgomery

1823  Susannah Montgomery

1825  William Montgomery

This may be of limited usefulness, though, since the decedent records microfilms only go up to 1810.